# getJSON not working with latest jquery but works with older jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am updating an older website that was using a version of jquery from 2009. I have removed the old jquery and added the line below to use the latest version of jquery:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The code below takes a user selected value from a dropdown and then the jquery populates another dropdown based on the users' selection.

**The following code works with the older version of jquery from 2009**, but when I switch to the latest jquery, it does not work. There are no errors. The console is clear. I added the alerts, but only alert 1 and alert 2 work ...alert 3 never shows up.

```
$(function(){
  $("select#area_name").change(function(){
    alert('1');
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    alert('2');
    $.getJSON("/props/res/get-area.php",{area_name: $(this).val()}, function(j){
      var options = '';
      alert('3');
      for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
        options += '<option value="' + j[i].optionValue + '">' + j[i].optionDisplay + '</option>';
      }
      $("select#arearesults").html(options);
    });
  });
});
```

I'm guessing the way jquery handles the getJSON part has changed, but I'm not a programmer and just helping a friend, so any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: What was the older version of jQuery?

Comment: If you look in the Network tab of dev tools, do you see a response to the AJAX request?

Comment: The older jquery says, " jQuery JavaScript Library v1.3.2" dated 2009-02-19 17:34:21 -0500 (Thu, 19 Feb 2009)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)

> The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callback methods introduced in jQuery 1.5 are deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. To prepare your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.

So change your code to:

```
$(function(){
  $("select#area_name").change(function(){
    alert('1');
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    alert('2');
    $.getJSON("/props/res/get-area.php",{area_name: $(this).val()}).done(function(j){
      var options = '';
      alert('3');
      for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
        options += '<option value="' + j[i].optionValue + '">' + j[i].optionDisplay + '</option>';
      }
      $("select#arearesults").html(options);
    });
  });
});
```

**EDIT**

As Barmar noted, passing the success callback as a parameter of $.getJSON hasn't been deprecated.

Also from the docs:

> Important: As of jQuery 1.4, if the JSON file contains a syntax error, the request will usually **fail silently**. Avoid frequent hand-editing of JSON data for this reason. JSON is a data-interchange format with syntax rules that are stricter than those of JavaScript's object literal notation. For example, all strings represented in JSON, whether they are properties or values, must be enclosed in double-quotes. For details on the JSON format, see http://json.org/.

Are you sure the JSON is in correct format? Please post a sample of the JSON.

Comment: He's not using any of the removed methods.

Comment: Providing the success function as an argument to `$.getJSON` hasn't been deprecated or removed.

Comment: Thanks! The JSON returned had single quotes. Replacing them with double quotes solved the problem. Works fine now :)

Answer (score 0):

I made a JSFiddle with your code (using a dummy JSON): https://jsfiddle.net/rqkeya45/

HTML:

```
<select id="area_name">
  <option value="1">Volvo</option>
  <option value="2">Saab</option>
  <option value="3">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="4">Audi</option>
</select> 
<select id="arearesults">
</select>
```

JS:

```
  $("select#area_name").change(function(){
    alert('1');
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    alert('2');
      jQuery.getJSON("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", {userId: $(this).val()}, function(j){
        var options = '';
        alert('3');
        for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
          options += '<option value="' + j[i].title + '">' + j[i].title + '</option>';
        }
        $("select#arearesults").html(options);
    });
  })
```

Your code works, so it seems there is a problem with the received JSON (maybe it is not syntactically correct).

Comment: The received JSON had single quotes. Per yvesmancera's answer I replaced them with double quotes and all is good now.